# How do I get rid of the commit hash in jenkins / github integration

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on a windows machine and have linked it with github.  When a project gets checked out to run, it includes the commit hash in the workspace name.

`D:\JENKINS_HOME_2\workspace\-cucumber-automation_789598-LSLIIMIHCM4PXQG6UGF6K6Z4L2PI4NLZUDLGHA2T6USOUQG4VZRQ`

which matches the

`<DRIVE>:\<JENKINS_HOME>\workspace\<project>_<branch>-<commit>`

On windows the extra characters with the commit hash creates a problem with character limits (only get 260 on windows).  How can I change it so the workspace directory doesn't include the commit hash (52 characters)?

Comment: That hash isn't the git commit.  It's a unique identifier for that job.